# Gospel writers who were not disciples of Jesus

Tags: gospels

Where did Mark and Luke get information about life of Jesus to write Gospel?

Comment: We have no way of knowing whether Luke was a disciple of Jesus, but we do know that Mark was; even though he was not one of the Apostles.

Answer (score 0):

**Where did Mark and Luke get information about life of Jesus to write Gospel?**

There is a very large field of study that attempts to put forth various theories of authorship by writing styles, word usage, and quite a bit of conjecture.

We do know of the twelve immediate disciples of Jesus. We also know of seventy others that were sent out on a particular ministry. It may be that there were even more. The criteria for being a disciple is given by Jesus;

> John 8:31-32  Then said Jesus to those Jews which believed on him, If
>   ye continue in my word, then are ye my disciples indeed;  And ye shall
>   know the truth, and the truth shall make you free.

We also have to consider that what was written was not just recording facts or gathering anecdotes.

> 2 Timothy 3:16  All scripture is given by inspiration of God, and is
>   profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for instruction
>   in righteousness:

Eyewitness accounts may have been collected, but the final authorship depends on the guiding hand of the Holy Spirit.

> 1 Thessalonians 2:13  For this cause also thank we God without
>   ceasing, because, when ye received the word of God which ye heard of
>   us, ye received it not as the word of men, but as it is in truth, the
>   word of God, which effectually worketh also in you that believe.
>
> 2 Peter 1:21  For the prophecy came not in old time by the will of
>   man: but holy men of God spake as they were moved by the Holy Ghost.
>
> John 14:26  But the Comforter, which is the Holy Ghost, whom the
>   Father will send in my name, he shall teach you all things, and bring
>   all things to your remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you.